# the data from form is not printing in console which is collected by post method express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

a form is in admin page to add products but the data (data is inclusive of an image file)in the form is not printing in the console instead it shows

> "{}
> POST /admin/add-product - - ms - -"

here is the code of the app.js (express generator)

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars')
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/', partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/' }))

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', usersRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use(fileUpload())

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

here is the codes in the admin file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let products=[{
    name:"Iphone 15"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by apple"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcR199XXubeTzwSceNjVSDZLSmAS9XKBkftsUbcSGADAGYXqqDRs17BYcd3jocTU_xeenejYWbzJbs394WBFqKBZOwJJcI3il9Pmcz8d3bA&usqp=CAE"
  
  },{
    name:"Samsung Galaxy S23 ultra"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by Samsung"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3uCOtqrOC3OSc1mveQKwrFN4bBVPsOk5FhSznuH-9bZMOU4qHs_-FYJscJ8nFGLDDZ3a_Cla-HCiHjkik3CaBRgsarJ-ZDKErAyLMLe2VRNBIeU1sti7Q&usqp=CAE"
  
  
  },{
    name:"Nothing phone 2"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by NOthing"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvcN7cV_G4iXn6uy8_RoByjPj35Vh1MA0nDKFdg6YNep0EzLTbTsV40YqO1tKxxjFQl8DFOfDW1-vOFTEikA_ZdlrWh9WDwHeFIln0xDuuy2BQRp2wcl4ZTw&usqp=CAE"
  
  },{
    name:"MI 13 ultra"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by apple"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcTv3moXySHfJ_y7ZuoC7S2gxrA2wWtvOe9Zw-YQiwX59uIBkR4IlZuptO9ThOnFiUGLSwpQjcOI8m0LCY19RMWJBcEn66jj_TioDlxIKCJgIekD60awjBYLIg&usqp=CAE"
  
  }]

  res.render('admin/view-products',{admin:true,products})
});
router.get('/add-product',function(req,res){

  res.render('admin/add-product',)
})

router.post('/add-product',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
})

module.exports = router;
```

here is the form html codes

```
    <section>
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6" >
                    <h2 class="text-center">Add Product</h2>
                    <form action="/admin/add-product"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label for="">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control">

                        <label for="">Catagory</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Catagory" class="form-control">
                        
                        <label for="">Price</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Price" class="form-control">

                        <label for="">Discription</label>
                        <input type="text " name="Discription" class="form-control">

                        <label for="">Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="Image" class="form-control">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I want the data to be rendered in the console with img file

Comment: You need to use a package that can parse formData aka `multi-part` requests, for example (multer)

Comment: can you send the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found that your fileupload module is use after the routes which should come after the fileupload app.use(fileupload())